# Laptop battery only changes to 29%

Tags: battery

I have a Dell Latitude e6400 laptop and recently installed Ubuntu 12.04.  Before, with Windows XP, my battery would charge to 100%.

Now, my battery charges to 29%.  No matter how long I charge it.

Any advice?

Comment: How old is your laptop and how much do you use it? It's possible the battery has just got old. Manufacturers only guarantee them for 6 months as they can degrade quite quickly.

Answer (score 2):

I think this may be a known bug.

The bug is https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/779586

The original reporter of the issue is running a Dell Inc. Latitude E6400, which is the same machine type and demonstrating the same situation you have described here.

Half an hour ago there was a new comment asking if there is any more information and if this is still a problem.

If you think it is the same issue you should help with this bug ticket It is quite old ( posted June 2011 ) and has had no updates since then so it will likely be closed if no new information is added.

Comment: In comment 2 ( https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/779586/comments/2 ) of the bug there is a lot of information to help you with providing information relating to this bug.